# Can I control a Chrome Extension externally from C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

would it be possible to control a Chrome Extension externally using a C/C++ script? So, for example, when my C script receives an

> if

trigger, it would send the command to an open Chrome Extension; e.g. to click a certain part of a page. This must be done using C, as my program is going to be heavily C based when completed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution that came to my mind:

A chrome extension can read files within its own directory.

So I would suggest to create a function in background.js that periodically (adjust the granularity as per your needs), reads some file within the extensions directory using chrome.extension.getURL, XMLHttpRequest and "GET" command.

Then execute the command stated in the file.

From your C/C++/Bash controlling program, you can send the commands.

Here is an example of the function:

```
function read_control_file() {
    var url = chrome.extension.getURL("control_cmd.txt");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // false so that request is processed immediately and we need not pass callback                                                
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();

    return request.responseText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Methos! But can the "control_cmd.txt" be edited (by the C program) and read (by Chrome) at the same time?

Comment: I don't know what kind of platform you are using but you can perhaps use file locks to allow exclusive access. Now in chrome extension you cannot access the file locks. But then you can create a simple local server using a micro-framework like Flask that would take care of locking the file and processing the GET request from the extension.

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you provide me with a code example for Flask?

Comment: It is actually very simple. See an example here:http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application        all that you have to do is populate that function to lock the file, then read the file and return the result.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Alternatively, a suggestion is to use selenium like framework unless you absolutely need to use extension.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, all this needs to work on a windows os, can Flask run on Linux?

Comment: It runs on both windows and linux.